# como puedo hacer un ListView horizontal en android?

Tags: android

me podrian decir cómo puedo hacer un ListView Horizontal, tengo un HorizontalScrollView pero éste se traba al momento de usarlo, pero no tengo ni idea de como hacer el ListView Horizontal.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En internet hay muchos tutoriales como ["Como hacer ListView Horizontales"](http://www.androidconnect.org/2012/05/10/como-hacer-listview-horizontales/), pero te recomiendo aún más usar [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) para tener un mejor performance, este es un [ejemplo](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html):

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(myDataset);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

este es el layout de `my_recycler_view.xml`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

En relación a tu pregunta de ¿como agregar botones?, dentro de tu método `onCreateViewHolder()` del Adapter que extiende de RecyclerView.Adapter puedes crear una vista que contenga botones:

```
@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                           .inflate(R.layout.mi_vista_con_botones, parent, false);
    // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
    ...
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}
```

Crearias algo similar a:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y para agregarle botones como  o en donde lo haria?

Comment: He actualizado mi respuesta, te recomiendo trates de realizar un ejemplo para que veas como funciona, aquí otro tutorial:  https://danielme.com/2015/08/15/android-recycler-view-listas/

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta y el link, claro hare varios ejemplos con el recyclerView para entenderlo mejor de nuevo gracias.